# AutoMapper bidirectional mapping

Tags: automapper, bidirectional

If I want to do bi-directional mapping, do I need to create two mapping?

`Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>() and Mapper.CreateMap<B, A>()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, because if you change the type of some property (for example DateTime -> string) it is not bidirectional (you will need to instruct Automapper how to convert string -> DateTime).

Comment: Makes sense, but it would be nice it the library TRIED to do the mapping as a convention, and you could explicitly disable it if it wasn't working.  For example, I map domain objects to view models and bidirectional mapping would work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 56):

Yes, but if you find yourself doing this often:

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static void Bidirectional<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<TDestination, TSource>();
    }
}
```

then:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>().Bidirectional();
```

Comment: while this may not answer the question, it certainly solves the underlying problem posed

Comment: Deprecated in 4.2, Removed in 5 :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194012/automapper-mapper-does-not-contain-definition-for-createmap

Answer (score 28):

This is now baked into AutoMapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: This does not work with custom mappings, only when the property names are the same in both classes.

Comment: @MichaelBrown even then, `ReverseMap` called on `IMappingExpression<SourceType, DestType>` returns an `IMappingExpression<DestType, SourceType>`, so the reverse custom mapping can then be defined.  I move this be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Great idea Eric!
I've added a return value, so the reverse mapping is configurable too.

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TDestination, TSource> Bidirectional<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        return Mapper.CreateMap<TDestination, TSource>();
    }
}
```